# asp authorization with some kind of commands and custom rights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I'm developing an ASP.MVC application and I need to add some authorization mechanism to allow users access some controllers, actions, entities and feilds. I need to allow admin user to modify rights as well.

For example i need:

- allow role MyRole1 to access MyPage1 (MyController1)
- allow role MyRole2 to access MyPage1 and execute
  MyController1.MyMethod1 to access array of entities MyEntity1 with
  fields MyEntity1.Field1,MyEntity1.Field2
- allow role MyRole3 same as MyRole2, but with fields MyEntity1.Field1,
  MyEntity1.Field3

which way is best to do it?